# ¿Cómo puedo mover texto de derecha a izquierda y viceversa como si fuese un banner en JFrame Java?

Tags: java, java-swing, hilos, jframe

Mi problema es que debo hacer que un "texto" se mueva de derecha a izquierda como un banner pero que las letras al llegar al límite del JFrame "rebote" y se mueva de izquierda a derecha.
También me gustaría saber cómo sería cuando vaya de izquierda a derecha (o cualquiera de los 2 casos) se reinicie y comience de nuevo del mismo lugar de izquierda a derecha(o derecha a izquierda en el otro caso).
Se debe usar Threads.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, esta web es para realizar preguntas sobre un tema en específico, te recomiendo que al menos intentes codificar algo y cuando tengas una duda que no te permite continuar nos la presentes o si tienes algo avanzado adjuntalo en la pregunta y con gusto te colaboraremos. Revisa [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para más información. Saludos ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mira con esta clase puedes hacer lo que pides:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class MoverLabel {
  JLabel label;
  Temporizador tempo=new 
  Temporizador(Temporizador.milisegundo,100);
  MoverLabel() {
    JFrame ventana= new JFrame();
    ventana.setBounds(0,0,700,400);
    ventana.setLayout(null);
    label=new JLabel("mensaje label");
    label.setBounds(0,0,150,30);
    label.setLayout(null);
    ventana.add(label);
    ventana.setVisible(true);
    mover(ventana.getWidth());
  }

  public void mover(int anchoFrame) {
    int anchototal=anchoFrame-label.getWidth()/2;
    int anchoVariable=0;
    for(int i=0;i<anchoFrame;i++) {
      anchoVariable=anchoVariable+i;
      if(anchoVariable>anchototal) {
        anchoVariable=anchoVariable-i;
        i=-i;
      }

      label.setLocation(anchoVariable,label.getY());
      tempo.espera();
    }
  }
}
```

Después en el método `main` solo instancias la clase:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
  MoverLabel mover=new MoverLabel();
}
```

Se me olvidaba la clase `Temporizador` es esta:

```
import java.util.Date;

public class Temporizador {
  static final int milisegundo=1;
  static final int  segundos=1000;
  static final int minutos=60000;
  static final int horas=3600000;
  Date tiempo=new Date();
  long esperar;

  Temporizador(int tipo,int cantidad) {
    esperar=tipo*cantidad;
  }

  void espera() {
    long ti=tiempo.getTime();         
    while(tiempo.getTime()-ti<esperar) {
      tiempo=new Date();
    }
  }
}
```